Undefined control sequence in my textcase.sty
I am new to the TeX StackExchange so my apologies if my question is not in the required formatting.
So I am facing an error in textcase.sty and latexrelease.sty file where I am getting an Undefined control sequence. \reserved@a { Upper } and similarly more such errors.
Here is a picture of my log (inserting the actual log was exceeding the word limit)

And here is my textcase.sty file in /usr/share/textlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/ folder.
%%
%% This is file `textcase.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% textcase.dtx  (with options: `package')
%% 
%% Source File: textcase.dtx
%% Copyright 1997 1998 2019 2022 2023 David Carlisle
%%
%% This file may be distributed under the terms of the LPPL.
%% See 00readme.txt for details.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{textcase}
       [2023/07/27 v1.04 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)]
\ifx\AddToNoCaseChangeList\@undefined\else
  \DeclareOption{overload}{}
  \ProcessOptions
  \PackageInfo{textcase}{Defining Legacy names}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \reserved@a #1
 {
  \cs_generate_variant:cn { text_ \str_lowercase:n {#1} case:nn } { V }
  \ExpandArgs { cnx } \NewExpandableDocumentCommand
    { MakeText#1case }
    { O{} +m }
    { \exp_not:c { MakeText#1case \c_space_tl \c_space_tl \c_space_tl }
                           [####1] {####2} }
  }
\reserved@a { Upper }
\reserved@a { Lower }
\cs_new_protected:cpn {
   MakeTextLowercase \c_space_tl \c_space_tl \c_space_tl } [#1] #2
  {%{
    \let \OE \oe
    \@@text@case@aux { lower } {#1} {#2}
  }%}
\cs_new_protected:cpn {
   MakeTextUppercase \c_space_tl \c_space_tl \c_space_tl } [#1] #2
  {%{
    \let \oe \OE
    \@@text@case@aux { upper } {#1} {#2}
  }%}
\ExplSyntaxOff
  \expandafter\endinput
\fi
\def\@uclcnotmath#1#2#3#4{\begingroup
      #1%
      \def\({$}\let\)\(%
      \let\UTF@two@octets@noexpand\@empty
      \let\UTF@three@octets@noexpand\@empty
      \let\UTF@four@octets@noexpand\@empty
      \def\NoCaseChange##1{\noexpand\NoCaseChange{\noexpand##1}}%
      \@nonchangecase\label
      \@nonchangecase\ref
      \@nonchangecase\ensuremath
      \def\cite##1##{\toks@{\noexpand\cite##1}\@citex}%
      \def\@citex##1{\NoCaseChange{\the\toks@{##1}}}%
      \def\reserved@a##1##2{\let#2\reserved@a}%
      \expandafter\reserved@a\@uclclist\reserved@b{\reserved@b\@gobble}%
      \protected@edef\reserved@a{\endgroup
          \noexpand\@skipmath#3#4$\valign$}%
      \reserved@a}
\def\@nonchangecase#1{\def#1##1{\NoCaseChange{#1{##1}}}}
\let\NoCaseChange\@firstofone
\def\@skipmath#1#2$#3${%
  \@skip@nonchangecase#1#2\NoCaseChange\valign
  \ifx\valign#3%
  \else
    $#3$%
    \expandafter\@skipmath\expandafter#1%
  \fi}
\def\@skip@nonchangecase#1#2\NoCaseChange#3{%
  #1{#2}%
  \ifx\valign#3%
  \else
    #3%
    \expandafter\@skip@nonchangecase\expandafter#1%
  \fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand\MakeTextUppercase{%
  \@uclcnotmath{\def\i{I}\def\j{J}}{##1##2}\uppercase}
\protected@edef\MakeTextUppercase#1{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\MakeTextLowercase{%
  \@uclcnotmath{}{##2##1}\lowercase}
\protected@edef\MakeTextLowercase#1{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}
\DeclareOption{overload}{%
  \expandafter\let\csname MakeUppercase \expandafter\endcsname
                  \csname MakeTextUppercase \endcsname
  \expandafter\let\csname MakeLowercase \expandafter\endcsname
                  \csname MakeTextLowercase \endcsname}
\ProcessOptions
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `textcase.sty'.


It is interesting to note that the same file was compiling before like a week ago. The problem began after I upgraded to Ubuntu 24. (Dunno how relevant this is, I am just mentioning the fact that the same thing worked before). And I have not touched the textcase.sty file at any time.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
EDIT: I am adding a small example where I was able to recreate the error.
%paper template%ramkarthik
%%%%%%%%%%% preamble defined - all files in the folder are required %%%%%%%%%%%

%\documentclass[aps,floatfix,amsmath,dstroke,amssymb,prlsymb,twocolumn, showpacs]{revtex4-2}%
%\documentclass[aps,pra,floatfix,amsmath,onecolumn,showpacs,12pt]{revtex4}

\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTtoptextmargin}{0.75in}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTbottomtextmargin}{1.1in}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTrighttextmargin}{0.622in}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTleftttextmargin}{0.622in}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease}
\documentclass[aps,pra,onecolumn,showpacs,12pt]{revtex4-2}
% \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\q}{\textquotesingle}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{subcaption}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand\x{\times}
\newcommand\y{\cellcolor{yellow!50}}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.2mm}} 
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{float}
\makeatletter
\let\newfloat\newfloat@ltx
\makeatother

\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

% \graphicspath{{Images/}}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% \geometry{top=0.6in, bottom=0.6in, left=0.4in, right=0.4in}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\linespread{1.2}
%%%%%% commands to change margins manually %%%%%%%%%%%
% \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5cm}
% \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-10cm}
% \addtolength{\textwidth}{}
% \addtolength{\topmargin}{-20}
% \addtolength{}{}
% \addtolength{\textheight}{}

%\usepackage[top    = 1.5cm,bottom = 1.50cm, left   = 2.50cm, right  = 2.50cm]{geometry}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    Sample text
\end{document}

And here is the log file from the point of error
! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@a ...rcase:n {#1}case:nn}{V}\ExpandArgs 
                                                  {cnx}\NewExpandableDocumen...
l.31 \reserved@a { Upper }
                          
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no c in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no x in font nullfont!

! LaTeX cmd Error: First argument of '\NewExpandableDocumentCommand' must be a
(cmd)              command.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.31 \reserved@a { Upper }
                          

The first argument of '\NewExpandableDocumentCommand' should be the document
command that will be defined. The provided argument 'MakeTextUppercase'
contains more than one token. Perhaps a backslash is missing?

LaTeX will ignore this entire definition.


! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@a ...rcase:n {#1}case:nn}{V}\ExpandArgs 
                                                  {cnx}\NewExpandableDocumen...
l.32 \reserved@a { Lower }
                          
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no c in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no x in font nullfont!

! LaTeX cmd Error: First argument of '\NewExpandableDocumentCommand' must be a
(cmd)              command.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.32 \reserved@a { Lower }
                          

The first argument of '\NewExpandableDocumentCommand' should be the document
command that will be defined. The provided argument 'MakeTextLowercase'
contains more than one token. Perhaps a backslash is missing?

LaTeX will ignore this entire definition.


) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 31--30
[] 
 []

\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip50
\bibsep=\skip51
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count289
)
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing natbib's \BibitemShut on input line 7588.
 (./revsymb4-2.sty
Package: revsymb4-2 2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ 
for documentation)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \REV@mathfrak on input line 125.
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Rollback for package 'amsmath' requested -> date 2020-02-02.
         Best approximation is the release introduced on 2019-04-01.
Package: amsmath 2023/05/13 v2.17o AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip52

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks32
\ex@=\dimen192
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \text on input line 28.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen193
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count290
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count291
\leftroot@=\count292
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410.
\classnum@=\count293
\DOTSCASE@=\count294
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box77
\strutbox@=\box78
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725.
\big@size=\dimen194
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count295
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count296
\dotsspace@=\muskip17
\c@parentequation=\count297
\dspbrk@lvl=\count298
\tag@help=\toks33
\row@=\count299
\column@=\count300
\maxfields@=\count301
\andhelp@=\toks34
\eqnshift@=\dimen195
\alignsep@=\dimen196
\tagshift@=\dimen197
\tagwidth@=\dimen198
\totwidth@=\dimen199
\lineht@=\dimen256
\@envbody=\toks35
\multlinegap=\skip53
\multlinetaggap=\skip54
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks36
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/bm.sty
Package: bm 2023/07/08 v1.2f Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
\symboldoperators=\mathgroup4
\symboldletters=\mathgroup5
\symboldsymbols=\mathgroup6
Package bm Info: No bold for \OMX/cmex/m/n, using \pmb.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 149.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bm on input line 219.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/relsize/relsize.sty
Package: relsize 2013/03/29 ver 4.1
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup7
\symAMSb=\mathgroup8
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frak on input line 111.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bbb on input line 113.
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Rollback for package 'array' requested -> date 2020-02-02.
         Best approximation is the release introduced on 2016-10-06.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array-2016-10-06.sty
Package: array 2016/10/06 v2.4d Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen257
\extrarowheight=\dimen258
\NC@list=\toks37
\extratabsurround=\skip55
\backup@length=\skip56
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty
Package: mathtools 2022/06/29 v1.29 mathematical typesetting tools

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2023/07/08 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count302
\calc@Bcount=\count303
\calc@Adimen=\dimen259
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen260
\calc@Askip=\skip57
\calc@Bskip=\skip58
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count304
\calc@Cskip=\skip59
)

LaTeX Warning: Suspicious rollback/min-date date given
               A minimal date of 2021/03/18 has been specified for package
               'mhsetup'.
               But this is in conflict with a rollback request to 2020-02-02.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty
Package: mhsetup 2021/03/18 v1.4 programming setup (MH)
)
\g_MT_multlinerow_int=\count305
\l_MT_multwidth_dim=\dimen261
\origjot=\skip60
\l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustabove_dim=\dimen262
\l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustbelow_dim=\dimen263
\l_MT_above_intertext_sep=\dimen264
\l_MT_below_intertext_sep=\dimen265
\l_MT_above_shortintertext_sep=\dimen266
\l_MT_below_shortintertext_sep=\dimen267
\xmathstrut@box=\box79
\xmathstrut@dim=\dimen268
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested release `2021-11-15' of LaTeX,
               but only release `2020-02-02' is available.

Package: tcolorbox 2024/01/10 version 6.2.0 text color boxes
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty
Package: verbatim 2023-11-06 v1.5v LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
\every@verbatim=\toks38
\verbatim@line=\toks39
\verbatim@in@stream=\read3
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
Package: environ 2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty
Package: trimspaces 2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count306
)
\tcb@titlebox=\box80
\tcb@upperbox=\box81
\tcb@lowerbox=\box82
\tcb@phantombox=\box83
\c@tcbbreakpart=\count307
\c@tcblayer=\count308
\c@tcolorbox@number=\count309
\l__tcobox_tmpa_box=\box84
\l__tcobox_tmpa_dim=\dimen269
\tcb@temp=\box85
\tcb@temp=\box86
\tcb@temp=\box87
\tcb@temp=\box88
)
\c@theorem=\count310

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
Rollback for package 'caption' requested -> date 2020-02-02.
         Best approximation is the release introduced on 2019-11-24.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption_2020-07-29.sty
Package: caption 2023/08/05 v3.4p Customizing captions (AR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
Rollback for package 'caption3' requested -> date 2020/07/29.
         Best approximation is the release introduced on 2019-11-24.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3_2020-07-29.sty
Package: caption3 2022/04/06 v1.13b caption3 kernel (AR)
Package caption3 Info: TeX engine: e-TeX on input line 63.
\captionmargin=\dimen270
\captionmargin@=\dimen271
\captionwidth=\dimen272
\caption@tempdima=\dimen273
\caption@indent=\dimen274
\caption@parindent=\dimen275
\caption@hangindent=\dimen276
Package caption Info: Unknown document class (or package),
(caption)             standard defaults will be used.
Package caption Info: \@makecaption = \long macro:#1#2->\par \vskip \abovecapti
onskip \begingroup \small \rmfamily \sbox \@tempboxa {\let \\\heading@cr \@make
@capt@title {#1}{#2}}\@ifdim {\wd \@tempboxa >\hsize }{\begingroup \samepage \f
lushing \let \footnote \@footnotemark@gobble \@make@capt@title {#1}{#2}\par \en
dgroup }{\global \@minipagefalse \hb@xt@ \hsize {\hfil \unhbox \@tempboxa \hfil
 }}\endgroup \vskip \belowcaptionskip  on input line 1057.
))

Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package),
(caption)                standard defaults will be used.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

\c@caption@flags=\count311
\c@continuedfloat=\count312
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/subcaption.sty
Rollback for package 'subcaption' requested -> date 2020-02-02.
         Best approximation is the release introduced on 2007/12/06.
Package: subcaption 2023/07/28 v1.6b Sub-captions (AR)
\c@subfigure=\count313
\c@subtable=\count314
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
\lst@mode=\count315
\lst@gtempboxa=\box89
\lst@token=\toks40
\lst@length=\count316
\lst@currlwidth=\dimen277
\lst@column=\count317
\lst@pos=\count318
\lst@lostspace=\dimen278
\lst@width=\dimen279
\lst@newlines=\count319
\lst@lineno=\count320
\lst@maxwidth=\dimen280

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty
File: lstmisc.sty 2023/02/27 1.9 (Carsten Heinz)
\c@lstnumber=\count321
\lst@skipnumbers=\count322
\lst@framebox=\box90
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg
File: listings.cfg 2023/02/27 1.9 listings configuration
))
Package: listings 2023/02/27 1.9 (Carsten Heinz)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Rollback for package 'textcomp' requested -> date 2020-02-02.
         Best approximation is the release introduced on 2020-02-02.
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty
Package: colortbl 2022/06/20 v1.0f Color table columns (DPC)
\everycr=\toks41
\minrowclearance=\skip61
\rownum=\count323
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty
Package: setspace 2022/12/04 v6.7b set line spacing
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarymatrix.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/appendix/appendix.sty
Package: appendix 2020/02/08 v1.2c extra appendix facilities
\c@@pps=\count324
\c@@ppsavesec=\count325
\c@@ppsaveapp=\count326
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count327
\float@exts=\toks42
\float@box=\box91
\@float@everytoks=\toks43
\@floatcapt=\box92
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithm.sty
Package: algorithm 2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithm' - floating enviro
nment

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
\@float@every@algorithm=\toks44
\c@algorithm=\count328
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.sty
Package: algorithmicx 2005/04/27 v1.2 Algorithmicx

Document Style algorithmicx 1.2 - a greatly improved `algorithmic' style
\c@ALG@line=\count329
\c@ALG@rem=\count330
\c@ALG@nested=\count331
\ALG@tlm=\skip62
\ALG@thistlm=\skip63
\c@ALG@Lnr=\count332
\c@ALG@blocknr=\count333
\c@ALG@storecount=\count334
\c@ALG@tmpcounter=\count335
\ALG@tmplength=\skip64
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty
Package: algpseudocode 

Document Style - pseudocode environments for use with the `algorithmicx' style
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshape
s.multipart.code.tex
File: pgflibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfnodepartlowerbox=\box93
\pgfnodeparttwobox=\box94
\pgfnodepartthreebox=\box95
\pgfnodepartfourbox=\box96
\pgfnodeparttwentybox=\box97
\pgfnodepartnineteenbox=\box98
\pgfnodeparteighteenbox=\box99
\pgfnodepartseventeenbox=\box100
\pgfnodepartsixteenbox=\box101
\pgfnodepartfifteenbox=\box102
\pgfnodepartfourteenbox=\box103
\pgfnodepartthirteenbox=\box104
\pgfnodeparttwelvebox=\box105
\pgfnodepartelevenbox=\box106
\pgfnodeparttenbox=\box107
\pgfnodepartninebox=\box108
\pgfnodeparteightbox=\box109
\pgfnodepartsevenbox=\box110
\pgfnodepartsixbox=\box111
\pgfnodepartfivebox=\box112
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarypositioning.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
Package: adjustbox 2022/10/17 v1.3a Adjusting TeX boxes (trim, clip, ...)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks45
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks46
)
\XKV@depth=\count336
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty
Package: adjcalc 2012/05/16 v1.1 Provides advanced setlength with multiple back
-ends (calc, etex, pgfmath)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
Package: trimclip 2020/08/19 v1.2 Trim and clip general TeX material

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty
Package: collectbox 2022/10/17 v0.4c Collect macro arguments as boxes
\collectedbox=\box113
)
\tc@llx=\dimen281
\tc@lly=\dimen282
\tc@urx=\dimen283
\tc@ury=\dimen284
Package trimclip Info: Using driver 'tc-pdftex.def'.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-pdftex.def
File: tc-pdftex.def 2019/01/04 v2.2 Clipping driver for pdftex
))
\adjbox@Width=\dimen285
\adjbox@Height=\dimen286
\adjbox@Depth=\dimen287
\adjbox@Totalheight=\dimen288
\adjbox@pwidth=\dimen289
\adjbox@pheight=\dimen290
\adjbox@pdepth=\dimen291
\adjbox@ptotalheight=\dimen292

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty
Package: ifoddpage 2022/10/18 v1.2 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
\c@checkoddpage=\count337
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty
Package: varwidth 2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
\@vwid@box=\box114
\sift@deathcycles=\count338
\@vwid@loff=\dimen293
\@vwid@roff=\dimen294
))
Class revtex4-2 Info: colortbl package is loaded. (Proceeding with fingers cros
sed.) on input line 88.


Class revtex4-2 Warning: Failed to patch the float package.

Class revtex4-2 Info: cite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 88.
Class revtex4-2 Info: mcite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 88.
Class revtex4-2 Info: multicol was not loaded (OK!) on input line 88.
(./paper_template.aux)
\openout1 = `paper_template.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 88.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 88.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 88.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 88.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 88.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 88.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 88.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 88.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 88.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 88.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 88.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 88.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 88.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 88.
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: float package is loaded.
Package caption Info: listings package is loaded.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
\c@lstlisting=\count339
\openout4 = `paper_templateNotes.bib'.


No file paper_template.bbl.

Package caption Warning: Unused \captionsetup[sub] on input line 68.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./paper_template.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right .


 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 22894 strings out of 476064
 446609 string characters out of 5792853
 1923975 words of memory out of 5000000
 44555 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558367 words of font info for 37 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 81 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 102i,4n,107p,436b,216s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on paper_template.pdf (1 page, 10064 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 15 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)


make a small but complete example that demonstrates the error.

Added in the edit. I hope it's good enough?

you have a new textcase and an old latex but have not shown enough of the log to know how that happened. Your image the editor texstudio? completely destroys the meaning of the error message in its useless "summary" of the errors

oh you have used latexrelease.sty to roll back your latex release to an older version. so what you show is expected.

So should I provide something else for better clarification of the error?

your example shows my guess was right, you have \RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease} so the error you show is expected.

your "small example" is far from small if your actual document preamble is like that you should adjust it! you specify tikz three times, array twice amsmath three times ...

\ExpandArgs was added to LaTeX in the 2022-06-01 Release.
You have used
\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease}

to roll back LaTeX to a release prior to that so \ExpandArgs is undefined.
However rolling back the format does not roll back all the other packages in your distribution so you are using a newer textcase that requires this command.
Unfortunately the texstudio "summary" of error messages still completely destroys the undefined command message so that it does not show which command is undefined  but that has been repeatedly reported since at least 2016
You should only use \RequirePackage{latexrelease} in very specific circumstances to avoid issues with packages, but if it is used it should always be used as the first line of the the file, never use it mid way down the preamble as here as changing the format between loading packages is almost certain to break something.

This resolved the problem! Thanks a lot! Turns out, I had revtex 4-2 files I had were causing problems with the \begin{document} because of which I rolled back to an earlier latex release as per some of the answers here. Revtex 4-2e along with your solution resolved the error and it's compiling now. Thanks a lot once again!
